# Loop for aggregated data frame in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with 58 columns labeled SD1 through to SD58 along with columns for date info (Date, Year, Month, Day).

I'm trying to find the date of the maximum value of each of the SD columns each year using the following code:

```
maxs<-aggregate(SD1~Year, data=SDtime, max)
SDMax<-merge(maxs,SDtime)
```

I only need the dates so I made a new df and relabeled the column as below:

```
SD1Max = subset(SDMax, select = c(Year, Date))
SD1Max %>%
  rename(
    SD1=Date
  )
```

I want to do the same thing for every SD column but I don't want to have to repeat these steps 58 times. Is there a way to loop the process?

Comment: Very probably "yes", but answer will not generally be offered unless you present a [MCVE]. It shows that you at least have mastered the basics of R and are not just abusing SO as a "free code-writing" resource. (Obviously we do not want to work with a 58+4 column example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no ties (multiple days with where the variable reached its maximum) this probably does what you want:

```
library('tidyverse')

SDtime %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches('^SD[0-9]{1,2}$')
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(value == max(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

You might want to `pivot_wider` afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I just ran into the issue of ties. Lots of 0s in some columns. Back to the drawing board I guess, thanks anyway

Comment: @Hunter  build upon this. I think you can use this result to get what you want